# error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `CameraOperator.InvertMouseY(float)'

Tags: c++

I am making a RTS style game and I have an error:

> error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `CameraOperator.InvertMouseY(float)'

Here is the script with the error:

```
camPos.y = CameraOperator.InvertMouseY (camPos.y);
```

I was told to do an instance of it but not sure what to do exactly.
I was told to use, but not sure how to write it.  If it replaces whole line or just part.

CameraOperator co;
co.InvertMouseY(camPos.y);

Here is whole script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Unit2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool selected = false;

    private void Update ()
    {
            if (renderer.isVisible && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                    Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
                    camPos.y = CameraOperator.InvertMouseY(camPos.y);
                    selected = CameraOperator.Selection.Contains (camPos);
            }
            if (selected) {
                    renderer.material.color = Color.red;
            } else {
                    renderer.material.color = Color.white;
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: What is `CameraOperator` ? If it is a class, then you need instance of it to access non-static members.

Comment: This might be helpful. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a member function of `CameraOperator` without having an instance of the declaring class.

Also `InvertMouseY()` seems to be declared as a member function, that needs to have an instance of the actual class in order to get called.

Answer (score 0):

`CameraOperator` is class and you're trying to call `InvertMouseY` as if it was a static function.

You need an instance,

```
CameraOperator co;
co.InvertMouseY(camPos.y);
```

Comment: would it replace  the whole line or part of this line, I'm a noobie.

Comment: You'll probably find that there is an instance of `CameraOperator` somewhere already, do a search and find out what else is using it.

Comment: And if there isn't then you have a design flaw or don't know what your own program does. Both are big problems.

Comment: I dont see anything else with a instance of CameraOperator